# Escaping characters in database

Tags: database, escaping

I'm trying to build my own simple database and I'm solving one final problem. I'm saving database data to file using my own format (really simplified JSON cut off of everything not required). That problem is escaping. I'm using (for example) `{` as char to signify upcoming name of table. Problem comes when someone uses `{` in tableName. How to solve this?

If I just change it to some another value, user may enter that replace string and after decoding saved database back to program readable way (arrays,...), these strings will be decoded and user won't get what he put in. I spend long time thinking about this and couldn't find any solution. Any ideas?

Comment: I would strongly suggest not inventing your own database... and JSON is already as simple as it gets really.  So, we'll assume this is an exercise.

Comment: Just don't allow it inside table names? Why would anyone need { inside a table name?? On a sidenote: you can resolve this problem by escaping the braces.

Comment: Really, sounds like you'd better go for `SQLite` or something. But: `json_encode` does escape everything for you for json, I see no reason why a `{` in a string should be a problem.

Comment: @Brad Of course, I just wanna try how good can I made it in short time

Answer (score 2):

You need an escape character of sort.  Don't just replace it.

Assuming `{` is ambiguous, to refer to a literal `{` you would use `\{`.  Now, the `\` is ambiguous, so simply allow escaping it as well with `\\`.  No more ambiguity!

Comment: What is the most simple way (for example in PHP) how to check if character is escaped?